# Can't change the LAN password

Tags: 16.04, password, lan

I had to change the password to connect to internet using my EAP account because system administrator wants to change it every month. But when I try to edit, going to edit connection and to the LAN setting changing the password to the new one, after I click save and reopen the tab I found the old one.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you the administrator of this system? If not ask the admin to do this.

Comment: @Rinzwind the password is actually changed in the system in the computer can't be changed I had to create a new connection and now it works